# PowerShell match names with user email addresses and format as mailto

Tags: html, powershell

So i have the below script which scans a drive for folders, it then pulls in a csv with folder names and folder owners and then matches them and outputs to HTML.

I am looking for a way to within this use PS to look up the users names in the csv grab their email address from AD and then in the output of the HTML put them as mailto code.

```
function name($filename, $folderowners, $directory, $output){
  $server = hostname
  $date =  Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"
  $a = "<style>"
  $a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;}"
  $a = $a + "Table{background-color:#ffffff;border-collapse: collapse;}"
  $a = $a + "TH{border-width:1px;padding:0px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
  $a = $a + "TR{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-        
  color:black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "body{ font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$c = " <br></br> Content"

$b = Import-Csv $folderowners
$mappings = @{}
$b | % { $mappings.Add($_.FolderName, $_.Owner) }



Get-ChildItem $directory | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select Name,   
@{n="Owner";e={$mappings[$_.Name]}} | sort -property Name | 
ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PostContent $c | 
Out-File $output
}

name "gdrive" "\\server\location\gdrive.csv" "\\server\location$"       
"\\server\location\gdrive.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this to the `select`:

```
@{n="email";e={"mailto:"+((Get-ADUser $mappings[$_.Name] -Properties mail).mail)}
```

You need to load the `ActiveDirectory` module before you can use the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

On server versions this module can be installed via Server Manager or `dism`. On client versions you have to install the [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) before you can add the module under "Programs and Features".

---

**Edit:** I would have expected `ConvertTo-Html` to automatically create clickable links from `mailto:user@example.com` URIs, but apparently it doesn't. Since `ConvertTo-Html` automatically encodes angular brackets as HTML entities and I haven't found a way to prevent that, you also can't just pre-create the property as an HTML snippet. Something like this should work, though:

```
ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PostContent $c | % {
  $_ -replace '(mailto:)([^<]*)', '<a href="$1$2">$2</a>'
} | Out-File $output
```

Comment: Just an FYI for future visitors, this requires the Active Directory Powershell Module, which requires the [RSAT Tools](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_rn=11&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=R8soErRMiasRtdfm3aZA0A&cp=34&gs_id=49&xhr=t&q=remote+server+administration+tools&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=remote+server+administration+tools&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.b2I&fp=9930a392078fcadf&biw=1920&bih=979&ion=1) for Windows 7 or greater OSes.

Comment: So it would look like  

    select Name, @{n="Owner";e={$mappings[$_.Name]}} @{n="email";e={"mailto:"+((Get-ADUser $mappings[$_.Name] -Properties mail).mail)} |

Comment: You're missing a comma between the 2nd and 3rd property, but in general it should look like that, yes.

Comment: Ok so if I put the username of the user in the email column it adds in mailto:email@mycompany.com thats great. But is there any way to actually make it a HTML Email link?

Comment: Ansgar that is excellent, you are a legend. I am not trying to work out a way to pull in a subject line to the email I can use <a href="$1$2?MYSUBJECT">$2</a> would it be possible to pull in the associated folder name as well do you think. I owe you a beer mate you have really helped here.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: I might have to post another question on this trying to use <a href="$1$2?subject=Folder Access Request&amp;body=Please can I have access to the following folder $directory">$2</a> but can't seem to figure a way to pull in the owners associated folder (still very new to PS as you can tell).

Comment: Please make this another question. It's not clear to me from your comment what the result should look like.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309816/powershell-include-folder-name-from-list-dynamically-into-mailto-html Thanks again for your help. Def owe you a beer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (avoiding the use of the AD Module, only because it's not on all of my workstations and this works just the same), and assuming you know the user name already:

```
#Setup Connection to Active Directory
$de = [ADSI]"LDAP://example.org:389/OU=Users,dc=example,dc=org"
$sr = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($de)
```

After I setup a connection to AD, I set my LDAP search filter. This takes standard ldap query syntax.

```
#Set Properties of Search
$sr.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]"Subtree"
$sr.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(samaccountname=$Username))"
```

I then execute the search.

```
#Grab user's information from OU. If search returns nothing, they are not a user and the script exits.
$SearchResults = $sr.FindAll()

if($SearchResults.Count -gt 0){
    $emailAddr = $SearchResults[0].Properties["mail"]

    $mailto = "<a href=`"mailto:$emailAddr`">Contact User</a>"


}
```

You can of course send the `$mailto` variable anywhere you want, and change it's html, but hopefully this gets you started.