# How to include folder name from list dynamically into mailto URL?

Tags: html, powershell

I have this script. It scans a folder location and maps the names of folders to that of the folder owners which is pulled from a CSV file it then gets the users email address from AD and adds it to a new column as a clickable `mailto:` link. This is then all output in a table on a HTML page.

Gone through a few iterations of this and now at the final stage.

My issue now is how to pull in the folder name to the mailto body HTML.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Encode($str) {
return ( $str -replace ' ', '%20' -replace '\n', '%0A%0D' )
}

function name($filename, $folderowners, $directory, $output){
$subject = Encode("Folder Access Request")
$body = Encode("Please can I have access to the following folder $directory")
$server = hostname
$date =  Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "Table{background-color:#ffffff;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width:1px;padding:0px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "TR{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "body{ font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$c = " <br></br> Content"
$c = $c +"<p>More Content</p>"
$x = ""

$b = Import-Csv $folderowners
$mappings = @{}
$b | % { $mappings.Add($_.FolderName, $_.Owner) }


       Get-ChildItem $directory | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select Name, Path, @{n="Owner";e={$mappings[$_.Name]}}, @{n="Email";e={"mailto:"+((Get-ADUser $mappings[$_.Name] -Properties mail).mail)}}  | sort -property Name | 
 ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PostContent $c | % {
  $body = Encode("Please can I have access to the following folder " + $_.Name)
  $_ -replace '(mailto:)([^<]*)', 
    "<a href=`"`$1`$2?subject=$subject&amp;body=$body`">`$2</a>"
} | Out-File $output
}

    name "gdrive" "\\server\departmentfolders$\location\gdrive.csv" "x:" "\\server\departmentfolders$\location\gdrive.html"
```

This now comes out and in the body of the email it shows the path but doesnt include the folder name just the path location \server\departmentfolders$ which is very nearly just need the folder name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use variables in the replacement string you have to use double quotes instead of single quotes around the string:

```
$_ -replace '...', "... $directory ..."
```

In that case you have to escape other elements in the replacement string, though, namely inner double quotes and back-references (`$1`, `$2`) to groups (`(...)`) in the regular expression:

```
$_ -replace '(...)(...)', "<a href=`"`$1`$2...`">..."
```

Also you should encode spaces (`%20`) and line breaks (`%0A%0D`) in the URL.

```
function Encode($str) {
  return ( $str -replace ' ', '%20' -replace '\n', '%0A%0D' )
}
```

The whole thing might look like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Encode($str) {
  return ( $str -replace ' ', '%20' -replace '\n', '%0A%0D' )
}

function name($filename, $folderowners, $directory, $output) {
  $subject = Encode("Folder Access Request")

  ...

  Get-ChildItem $directory | ... |
    ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PostContent $c | % {
      if ( $_ -match '^<tr><td>([^<]*)' ) {
        $body = Encode("Please can I have access to the following folder " +
                       "{0}\{1}" -f ($directory, $matches[1]))
      }
      $_ -replace '(mailto:)([^<]*)', 
        "<a href=`"`$1`$2?subject=$subject&amp;body=$body`">`$2</a>"
    } | Out-File $output
}

...
```

Comment: Hmmm I tried a straight copy and paste and can't seem to get it to work. Also the &amp; need to be there in the HTML so the mailto knows we are now looking at the next section which is then body.

Comment: `&amp;` and `&` both work. I changed the sample code to make it a little clearer. If that doesn't help, please update your question with the modified code, so I can take a look at it.

Comment: I think I understand where the problem is. You want the child folders of `$directory` to show up in the mail body, not `$directory` itself, correct? In that case you need to move the definition of `$body` inside the `ForEach-Object` loop. See updated answer. You probably should use `$_.Path` instead of `$_.Name`, though (add `Path` to `select` statement).

Comment: My bad, actually. I overlooked that `ConvertTo-Html` comes before the loop, so you don't have access to `$_.Name` (or `$_.Path`) in the loop anymore. I added some code to extract the name from the first field of the HTML table. Please see if the updated sample now works as desired.